# Upgrade spring boot app from 2 to 3, fail to 'Set-Cookie' on auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I'm attempting to upgrade my angular spring boot 2.x.x app to spring boot 3.x.x. I am seeing my authentication REST call to my user endpoint NOT return the 'Set-Cookie' header after it authenticates via the basic auth header. The call returns a status 200 as the authentication works for this one call.  All subsequent secured REST calls return a 401 status as the session cookie is never set due to lack of 'Set-Cookie' return on auth call.

Here are the request response headers for the auth call.  Note the lack of 'Set-Cookie' in response.  In spring boot 2.x.x, the 'Set-Cookie' was always returned on this call.

```
===> the request headers
GET /api/users/current HTTP/1.1
Host: retrospect.wspfeiffer.com:8443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://retrospect.wspfeiffer.com:8443/login
Cookie: SESSION=N2IzZmU4MDEtZjUwMC00MGU1LTllNDItMzVjODkzZWY1NGE2
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

====> the response headers
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2023 14:48:29 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

In spring boot 2.x.x, the 'Set-Cookie' is set and the cookie is used for all subsequent rest calls. This technique is documented here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ and has worked for me up until the spring boot 3 upgrade. Any ideas on this?

Adding security config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/open/api/**").permitAll()
                                                .requestMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                                         "",
                                         "/",
                                         "/*.html",
                                         "/favicon.ico",
                                         "/*.css",
                                         "/*.js",
                                         "/*.map",
                                         "/assets/**",
                                         "/error").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addExposedHeader("Content-Type");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String,PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("sha256", new StandardPasswordEncoder());

        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security 6 [requires explicit save of the `SecurityContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository), the HTTP Basic is a stateless authentication mechanism, therefore it won't be saved to the session by default. To do that, you must configure the  `BasicAuthenticationFilter` to use a `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`, like so:

```java
http
        // ...
        .httpBasic((basic) -> basic
            .addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<BasicAuthenticationFilter>() {
                @Override
                public <O extends BasicAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O filter) {
                    filter.setSecurityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
                    return filter;
                }
            })
        );
```

[This is documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#storing-stateless-authentication-in-the-session) in the Spring Security documentation.

Spring Security 6.1 will also introduce a [new method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12031) in the HTTP Basic DSL to configure the `SecurityContextRepository`.

EDIT:

In Spring Security 6.1, you can just do:

```java
http.httpBasic((basic) -> basic.securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()))
```

Comment: Bigs thanks.  Found this same solution independently/simultaneously on Github issues on Spring Security project.  Did not see this section in docs until your answer. Will update my code to this solution and await the HTTP Basic DSL for simpler implementation.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thought I'd follow up with simpler dsl version:

`http.httpBasic((basic) -> basic.securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()))`